# NTP metrics using prometheus

Tags: prometheus, metrics, ntp, prometheus-node-exporter

I am trying to get NTP metrics in prometheus. I have node-exporter running as docker container and enabled --collector.ntp in CMD, but still I don't see any metrics. Upon checking node-exported docker container logs I see:

```
caller=collector.go:169 level=error msg="collector failed" name=ntp duration_seconds=0.000119723 err="couldn't get SNTP reply: read udp 127.0.0.1:33806->127.0.0.1:123: read: connection refused"
```

All I can see ntp metrics in my localhost:9100/metrics is

```
node_scrape_collector_duration_seconds{collector="ntp"} 0.000153012
node_scrape_collector_success{collector="ntp"} 0
```

Any suggestions please

Comment: Change this line in /etc/chrony.conf file as from

`allow 192.168.0.0/16`

TO

`allow 0.0.0.0/0` and restart chronyd using `systemctl restart chronyd`